# Alternative to soldering for an Arduino board

Tags: arduino

I’ve got an Arduino board and I can’t seem to find an alternative to soldering to keep wires connected to the board’s inputs/outputs.

I don’t really want to solder it, since this is my first board and I’m just experimenting, and eventually I might take apart my current project or have to change some cables, etc.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** The board is a Digispark ATtiny85 board with just pin holes. It did come with male headers, they are just not soldered in.

Comment: Please show what your board is. Some boards have 0.1" headers, if it doesn't have something like that you'll have to solder

Comment: You can get a proto-board for a few dollars, and also a mini-breadboard for solderless prototyping. https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/proto-shield-rev3-uno-size?selectedStore=us

Comment: What board? There are lots of Arduino boards.

Comment: What kind of inputs/outputs your board has, and what connection methods have you tried and why they did not work? Does the board has just PCB holes or are there pin headers? Which type of pin header?

Comment: _”ATTINY85 Board with just pin holes, however, they did come with male headers, just not soldered in”_ Solder the header. Job done. No more soldering.

Comment: Like winny and PStechPaul said: solder the header, then you can easily prototype with a [Mini Breadboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCEgh.png). This way you can re-use your hardware for other projects.

Comment: Please link a picture of the actual board used. There seems to be a lot of similar ones. Some have 0.1'' headers and then the solution is to solder a socket and/or header strip there.

Answer (score 1):

The main alternative to soldering is to use male to female jumper wires that have Dupont connectors. You'd have to solder on the male headers provided with your Arduino-like Digispark. You would use these in conjunction with a solderless breadboard.

If you need to avoid soldering entirely you can buy press-fit headers (hammer headers). I haven't tried those and would be sceptical. You might be better off with test-point connectors and suitable leads (hook-clip, mini-grabbers, crocodile-clip test-leads, etc)

[image]

An older alternative to soldering is wire-wrapping - I believe you can still buy the wire and tools.

You might like to practice desoldering using solder-wick.